# Append string of conditions to file using sed

Tags: bash, sed, centos

I have to make a script which looks at `/etc/gdm/Xsession` and adds `-a ! -x "$HOME/.xsession"` to it if needed.

1) I want to check if the file already contains the added part.
Using grep, I tried this:

```
if ! grep -q '-a ! -x "$HOME/.xsession"' "$xsessionScript"
```

It doesn't work as grep tries to interpret everything that's between the simple quotes.

2) If I find that the file wasn't modified, I want to append `-a ! -x "$HOME/.xsession"` to the if statement: `if [ "$1" != "default" -a "$1" != "custom" ]` so that it looks like:

```
if [ "$1" != "default" -a "$1" != "custom" -a ! -x "$HOME/.xsession" ]
```

I try doing it using sed:

```
sed -i.bck '/\"$1" != "default" -a "\$1" != "custom"/a  -a ! -x "$HOME/.xsession"'
```

but this will create a new line instead of adding the string after "custom".

Please help me!

Thanks a lot :)

Btw, I'm on CentOs 6.6.1, sed 4.2.1, bash 4.1.2

**EDIT:**

The file I want to edit looks like this:

```
[...]
case $# in
    [...]
    case "$1" in
    [...]
    *)
        if [ "$1" != "default" -a "$1" != "custom" ]; then # I want this line to become:
====> # if [ "$1" != "default" -a "$1" != "custom" -a ! -x "$HOME/.xsession" ]
        exec $CK_XINIT_SESSION $SSH_AGENT /bin/sh -c "exec -l $SHELL -c \"$1\""
        fi
        ;;
    esac
esac
fi
[...]
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand... but I think `grep -Fq` is what you are looking for? it would also help if you give two input samples and expected output for that.. one where you need to add and one where you do not want to modify

Comment: Hi @Sundeep I added a piece of the file. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# I use variables for clarity
main='"\$1" != "default" -a "\$1" != "custom" '
appendix='-a ! -x "\$HOME/.xsession" '

sed -i.bck -r "s|($main)($appendix)?|\1$appendix|" input.txt
```

#### Explanation

1. `sed 's|||'` construction is the same as the `sed 's///'`.
2. `s|($main)($appendix)?|` - mean this: pattern must contain the `$main` part, but the `$appendix` part is optional. The `$appendix` can be present and it can be absent.
3. `|\1$appendix|` - replace the pattern to the `$main` (I use the `\1` capture group instead of the `$main` variable for brevity) + $appendix.

So, we got the desired behaviour:

- if line contain only `main` part, it will be replaced to the `main + appendix`.
- if the line already contain `main + appendix`, it will be replaced to the same. In other words, it remains unchanged.

#### Testing

**Input**

```
[...]
case $# in
    [...]
    case "$1" in
    [...]
    *)
        if [ "$1" != "default" -a "$1" != "custom" ]; then
        exec $CK_XINIT_SESSION $SSH_AGENT /bin/sh -c "exec -l $SHELL -c \"$1\""
        fi
        ;;
    esac
esac
fi
[...]
```

**Output**

```
[...]
case $# in
    [...]
    case "$1" in
    [...]
    *)
        if [ "$1" != "default" -a "$1" != "custom" -a ! -x "$HOME/.xsession" ]; then
        exec $CK_XINIT_SESSION $SSH_AGENT /bin/sh -c "exec -l $SHELL -c \"$1\""
        fi
        ;;
    esac
esac
fi
[...]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep 'a | -x "$HOME/.xsession"' file.sh > /dev/null` to check if it contains this test. If it doesn't, grep will return 1.

`if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; then echo '-a ! -x "$HOME/.xsession"' >> /etc/gdm/Xsession` should do it.

The if checks if grep found anything; if it didn't the echo will append the text to the Xsession file

If you can add a sample of how your Xsession looks and what you expect it to look like after you execute the script, I can try give you an example.

**Update**: try this one

`if [ "$1" != "default" -a "$1" != "custom" -a ! $(grep 'a | -x "$HOME/.xsession"' "$xsessionScript")]`

Comment: Thanks for the grep part. 

But for the insertion of the string, I don't want to append it at the end of the file, but inside the "if" statement (see updated original post)